error[E0369]: cannot multiply `f64` by `f64` in Rust
I am a Rust learner. I want to make a function that multiplies an euclid::Vector3D<f64,U> by an f64. I have this code:
use euclid::Vector3D;

fn main() {
    fn scale_vector<f64,Unit>(vec: Vector3D::<f64, Unit>, scale: f64) -> Vector3D::<f64, Unit> {
        Vector3D::<f64, Unit>::new(vec.x * scale, vec.y * scale, vec.z * scale)
    }
    enum Meters {}
    let vec = Vector3D::<f64,Meters>::new(1., 2., 3.);
    let scaled_vec = scale_vector(vec, 2.);

    println!("Original vector: {:?}", vec);
    println!("Scaled vector: {:?}", scaled_vec);
}

but cargo run gives me
error[E0369]: cannot multiply `f64` by `f64`
 --> src/main.rs:5:42
  |
5 |         Vector3D::<f64, Unit>::new(vec.x * scale, vec.y * scale, vec.z * scale)
  |                                    ----- ^ ----- f64
  |                                    |
  |                                    f64
  |
help: consider restricting type parameter `f64`
  |
4 |     fn scale_vector<f64: std::ops::Mul<Output = f64>,Unit>(vec: Vector3D::<f64, Unit>, scale: f64) -> Vector3D::<f64, Unit> {
  |                        +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Why? What is the way of doing this?

With scale_vector<f64,Unit> the type f64 becomes shadowed with an eponymous type parameter that is not restricted by any trait bounds and thus does not implement Mul.

Running Clippy might help you find unusual constructs such as that one in the future. https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#/builtin_type_shadow

In fn scale_vector(), you added f64 as a generic type. Just remove it and it will compile:
    fn scale_vector<Unit>(vec: Vector3D::<f64, Unit>, scale: f64) -> Vector3D::<f64, Unit> {
        Vector3D::<f64, Unit>::new(vec.x * scale, vec.y * scale, vec.z * scale)
    }

